# Can you increase specifity by nesting class inside of another class?

Tags: css, sass, less

Would this

```
.class{
 .subclass{ }
}
```

be same as

```
.class{}
.subclass{}
```

are there any diffrences apart from visual ones?

Comment: the second way is 2 seperate classes, you would need to miss off the `{}` after `.class` in the second example for the class to be nested

Comment: The first nested would only work using sass or less. To reference the same nested class in plain CSS - you would reference `.class .subclass {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting in SASS does exactly that. It increases specificity of the selector.

[Play with this gist on SassMeister.](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b6da754f371eba97fde901b5e88073f0)

```
.class {
  .subclass {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

compiles to:

```
.class .subclass {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does increase specificity.

```
.class {
    .subclass{}
}
```

after being compiled into regular css is:

```
.class .subclass {
}
```

While your second example stays exactly the same after compiling.

Of course this only works if you are using SASS / LESS.